# Orbit of $A_{100}$ acting a set of size $90$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G=A_{100}$ and assume $G$ acts on set $\Omega$ with $|\Omega|=90$. Prove that $G$ has $90$ orbits of size $1$ on $\Omega$.

**My attempts**

Using the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, for any $x\in \Omega$, we have $$|O_x||G_x| = |G| = \frac{100!}{2},$$
where $O_x$, $G_x$ are the orbit and stabilizer of $x$, respectively.

Also, we know that since $O_x\leq \Omega$, its order must divide $90=1\cdot2\cdot3^2\cdot 5$.

Meanwhile, note that $G_x\leq G$ and that $G$ is simple.

Then we can rule out $|O_x|=2$ because that would imply that $G_x$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$, contradicting $G$ being simple.

But I can't figure out how to rule out the rest of the possible orders of $O_x$ and deduce that $|O_x|=1$.

Or should I approach from a different angle? I tried using the class equation and the permutation representation of $G$ but neither worked for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Concentrate on $G_x$. I claim that the index $[A_{100}:G_x]$ is either equal to $1$ or $\ge100$. If $H\le A_{100}$ is a subgroup of index $n$, then the action of $A_{100}$ on the cosets of $H$ gives a homomorphism of groups $\phi:A_{100}\to S_n$. Given that $A_{100}$ is simple, what can you say about the kernel? Hence about the image? Hence about $n$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Got it! Thanks a lot for the help!